# const auto and object constancy

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

Imagine some function (`RetrieveResult`), returning an object by pointer/reference/value - I don't know and don't want to know, because things may change. I just want to store the result, using `auto` and also protect that object from accidental changing in the current scope or, for example, if the object is propagated upwards.

It is quite intuitive just to write:

```
const auto result = RetrieveResult();
```

and everything works fine, if `RetrieveResult` returns an object by value or by reference. But if the function returns a pointer, constancy is applied to that pointer, not to the object the poiter points to. What way I still can change the object. Writing

```
const auto const result = ....
```

results in the compilation error:

> duplicate 'const'

Of course, I can declare variable like this:
    const auto* ...
    const auto* const...

But that way ties me close to pointers, i.e. it isn't a universal solution.

Is it possible to preserve true constancy, and, in the same time, provide flexibility (independency of the concrete type)?

Comment: "I don't and don't want to know" How are you supposed to access the object if you don't know what it is? For all you know, it could be a class with overloaded `->` and you think it's a pointer :P

Comment: @Rakete1111, For example, I may just forward the object, not touching it

Comment: @Alexey If you forward it why do you care if the pointer it points to is `const` or not?

Comment: In VS2015, `const auto const` doesn't produce any compiler errors, just a warning: `warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once`

Comment: @Rakete1111, there always may be some reasons ) C++ has a powerful syntax, and I'm trying to perceive all these devil things )

Answer (score 4):

There is experimental support for this utility called `std::propagate_const` in the Library Fundamentals v2.  You can write a type trait on top of that that does this for you (if you do not have `std::propagate_const` you can consider writing it yourself :))

```
namespace {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<true>>
    PropagateConst {
        using type = T;
    };
    template <typename T>
    PropagateConst<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<
            decltype(*std::declval<std::decay_t<T>>()), 
            decltype(*std::declval<std::decay_t<T>>())>::value>> {
        using type = std::propagate_const_t<std::decay_t<T>>;
    };

    template <typename T>
    using PropagateConst_t = typename PropagateConst<T>::type;

    template <typename Type>
    decltype(auto) propagate_const(Type&& in) {
        return PropagateConst_t<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<Type>>{in};
    }
} // <anonymous>

// then use it like this
const auto result = propagate_const(RetrieveResult());
```

---

Note that the solution I have above only checks for the presence of an `operator*` in the possible pointer type.  You might want to consider writing a more extensive test for that.

Also note that this uses reference collapsing in the `propagate_const` example so expect at least a move to happen in cases where you might be expecting elision.  You can optimize it based on your use case.  I just thought I would outline what was in my head.  Maybe that would help

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
struct very_const_t { using type=T; };
template<class T>
struct very_const_t<T*> { using type=typename very_const_t<T>::type const*; };
template<class T>
struct very_const_t<T&> { using type=typename very_const_t<T>::type const&; };

template<class T>
typename very_const_t<T>::type&&
very_const( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
```

then:

```
const auto result = very_const(RetrieveResult());
```

note that this can block elision.  I carefully do not block move semantics, however.

This does not move `const` into smart pointers.  If you want that:

```
template<class T, class D>
struct very_const_t<std::unique_ptr<T,D>> { using type=std::unique_ptr<typename very_const_t<T>::type const, D>; };

template<class T>
struct very_const_t<std::shared_ptr<T>> { using type=std::shared_ptr<typename very_const_t<T>::type const>; };
```

will do it for `unique` and `shared`.